# Is this Valid Oracle Stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have to call a stored procedure from oracle sever that not under our control
so after digging i wrote a script in groovy to know the content of this procedure and 
it was like this

```
PROCEDURE SAM2_update_message_status (
      msg_id        IN   NUMBER,
      sam4_id       IN   NUMBER,
      msg_status    IN   NUMBER,
   smsc_answer   IN   VARCHAR2
   )
   IS
   BEGIN
   UPDATE TRC_MESSAGES_REMINDERS
   SET msg_status = msg_status
   WHERE MSG_ID = msg_id;
   COMMIT;
```

from my programing experience this is meaningless  `MSG_ID = msg_id,msg_status = msg_status`
but i don't know if it's the same in oracle.

I called it but no errors and the values i sent not reflected on the table.

Is this a Valid procedure?

Thanks

Comment: It's not only meaningless, it's expensive: the procedure will update every row in the table (at least, where MSG_ID is not null)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the scope rules, it will use the column name before the parameter name, so that update isn't doing anything.  I always stick "p_" before each parameter name to avoid conflicts like that.

Comment: I've worked at places that also use some sort of prefix to indicate a variable or parameter.  One of them used "IN_", "OUT_", and "INO_" to also indicate the direction of the parameter.

Comment: "Best practice" according to Oracle is to always use aliases: e.g. `UPDATE TRC_MESSAGES_REMINDERS t SET t.msg_status = SAM2_update_message_status.msg_status WHERE t.MSG_ID = SAM2_update_message_status.msg_id`